# how to increase size of home directory after increasing size of the disk

Tags: partition, disk

I just cloned my 256 GB ssd disk to 2TB disk using disk cloner machines. However, what I want to do is increase the size of "scientific_hep--node0-home" by 1.6TB. I am running on centos7.
Below is the output of lsblk command.

[image]

Comment: Which filesystem is used on that volume?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `lvextend` command to increase the size of a logical volume in `LVM`.

```
lvextend -L +1.6T /dev/mapper/vg_scientific_hep-node0-home
```

then:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_scientific_hep-node0-home
```

or

```
xfs_growfs /mnt/mount_point
```

Comment: You also have to use resize2fs or growfs to align filesystem to its new size without having to remount it.

Comment: @Gilles Not worked. Getting "skip_dev_dir: Couldn't split up device name vg_scientific_hep-node0-home.
  "/dev/mapper/vg_scientific_hep-node0-home": Invalid path for Logical Volume."

Comment: @francoisP Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: You need to adapt the path

Comment: `lvextend` can be run with `--resizefs` in order to avoid the separate resizing step. The problem with the call is that the LV is not addressed with a device file path but with the notation `VG/LV_NAME` i.e. `scientific_hep/node0-home`